# change background colour of p element when touch

Tags: html, css

This html page may have more than one `<p>` element. I wish to change the background of the one that gets touched by the mobile user. And if the user touches another, then the previous touched paragraph returns back to the its original background colour "default white".

I tried few selectors for no avail. How can it be done with CSS? thanks

**edit**
There are 2-3 lines of data which need to be displayed to the user, I used paragraph for each group of 2-3 lines, since I can do a bit of formatting as well as showing the different pieces of data like a vertical list.
So I wish to be able to select an item from the "list" and apply other actions relating to the selected item.

```css
.selectable:focus {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<template name="myName">
  <p class="selectable"><b>{{value.[0]}}</b><br/>{{value.[1]}}<br/>{{value.[2]}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Paragraph elements aren’t focus-able by themselves. You’ll need to add a `tabindex` for that to work.

Comment: @CBroe what about change focus to another action what works with mobile web app? or maybe change the paragraph element to another that can display text?

Comment: Just to clarify, is CSS a requirement? Are you purposefully avoiding javascript/jquery?

Comment: @jefffabiny CSS is preferred but not required.

Comment: `:hover` works in some mobile browsers, in that they toggle into the hover state on first tab on an element.

Comment: _“So I wish to be able to select an item from the "list" and […]”_ – that would require that you _have_ individual items (HTML elements) to begin with – which you currently don’t, if all of the content resides inside a single `p` element. You want a list, so use one – `ul`/`ol` and `li`.

Comment: _“[…] and apply other actions relating to the selected item”_ – that won’t work either, using CSS alone – all you can do with CSS is change formatting, but not trigger any “actions.”

Comment: @CBroe I re edited my edit, there are may paragraphs, one per 2-3 lines

Comment: In that case you can use jquery to create an event listener. I provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the @CBroe suggestion, you could do the following:

```
<p class="selectable" tabindex="0"> Paragraph 1 </p>
<p class="selectable" tabindex="0"> Paragraph 2 </p>
<p class="selectable" tabindex="0"> Paragraph 3 </p>
<p class="selectable" tabindex="0"> Paragraph 4 </p>

.selectable:focus {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9v00t2v/).

You can learn more about tabindex [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

Answer (score 0):

- Add a listener for the event you want
- Apply the listener to the elements you want
- Add the functionality you want, in this case: adding a class to give a background color (and removing the previous element's color).

  ```
  $("p").on("tap",function(){
      $('.add-color').removeClass('add-color');
      $(this).addClass('add-color');
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery you can do it like this:

jQuery:

```
$("p.selectable").click(function(){
  $("p.selectable").removeClass("clicked");
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
})
```

CSS:

```
p.selectable {
  background:white;
  height:100px;
}
p.selectable.clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko48u75c/1/). It is hard to do with CSS only. CSS is ment to change formatting. If you want to trigger actions, use javascript. (It can be done with a hacky method in CSS like adding a invisble checkbox over the paragraphs or something but lets not get into that)

EDIT: apparently can also be achieved by [adding a `tabindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484210/3640844) as @CBroe suggested. Neat trick :) However, if you want to trigger more actions when the paragraphs are clicked, use javascript approach. If you only want to change the style, you can use this CSS only trick.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a hacky way of doing it, but you can utilize the `:checked` pseudo-selector in combination with the text as a way to toggle its "selected" state.

```css
.selectable {
  display: none;
}

.selectable:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="unique-id" class="selectable">
<label for="unique-id">
  <b>{{value.[0]}}</b><br/>{{value.[1]}}<br/>{{value.[2]}}
</label>
```

The benefit to this is that you are not reliant on JavaScript and it should be pretty stable across the various devices and platforms.

Let me know if you have any questions or need further clarification!